# QPushButton of minimal width in QHBoxLayout?

Tags: qt, qt5, qpushbutton, qlayout

I want to create the QPushButton with text "X" to close the window. I want to place it to the button's bar. To do so, I made QHLayout.

```
layTop=QHBoxLayout()

self.btnMenu=QPushButton("Menu") #just as sample of button with normal size
layTop.addWidget(self.btnMenu)

btnX=QPushButton("X")  #I need it small
btnX.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Preferred) #I try this, but it's not work as I expected
layTop.addWidget(btnX)
```

But, "X" button is as big as other buttons. How to make it narrow?

(screenshot for this code is below)

[image: expectation-vs-reality for SizePolicy]

Comment: You may need to set your slider as `QSizePolicy.Expanding`, or `QSizePolicy.Maximum`, so that it will actually expand and force your button to shrink

Comment: you may use setMinimumSize(w,h) and setMaximumSize(w,h) of your desired width and height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `QToolButton` instead of `QPushButton`:

[image]

Comment: typo: `QToolButton`